# Does blender have an alternative to tension map?

Tags: animation, texturing, node-editor, topology

I require an animation friendly way to produce high-quality skin deformation at the face level.  Skin compression and stretching results in tiny wrinkles. Does blender have an alternative to tension map? If not, will they develop one? I really want to use 100% Blender in production.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6G8SkBQngvw Theres an addon for it, not sure what version its up to though. It'd be nice to have an addon packaged in blender releases.